# Verify Artifactory download in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I'm using the Jfrog Artifactory plugin in my Jenkins pipeline to pull some in-house utilities that the pipelines use.  I specify which version of the utility I want using a parameter.

After executing the server.download, I'd like to verify and report which version of the file was actually downloaded, but I can't seem to find any way at all to do that. I do get a buildInfo object returned from the server.download call, but I can find any way to pull information from that object.  I just get an object reference if I try to print the buildInfo object.  I'd like to abort the build and send a report out if the version of the utility downloaded is incorrect.

The question I have is, "How does one verify that a file specified by a download spec is successfully downloaded?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is only available on scripted pipeline at the moment, and is described in the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-GettingDependenciesandArtifactsfromtheBuild-Info).

For example:

```
node {
def server = Artifactory.server SERVER_ID
def downloadSpec = readFile 'downloadSpec.json'
def buildInfo = server.download spec: downloadSpec

if (buildInfo.getDependencies().size() > 0) {
    def localPath = buildInfo.getDependencies()[0].getLocalPath()
    def remotePath = buildInfo.getDependencies()[0].getRemotePath()
    def md5 = buildInfo.getDependencies()[0].getMd5()
    def sha1 = buildInfo.getDependencies()[0].getSha1()
    echo localPath
}

server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
}
```

Comment: Would you happen to have a pointer to documentation to what else is in buildInfo.  I've searched for hours to no avail.

[Edit]. Finally found something:  https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/blob/master/build-info-api/src/test/java/org/jfrog/build/api/ArtifactTest.java

Comment: Only things that are documented in the documentation I referred to above. Most of it is for configuration. If you'd like to look at the code, things that are whitelisted [here](https://github.com/jfrog/jenkins-artifactory-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfrog/hudson/pipeline/common/types/buildInfo/BuildInfo.java).